# Creating a simple site to display my apps, having some routing issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a site where I display my apps. I use MVC 3.

My Home controller is a typical overview page where I'll list all my apps. Then there is the App controller, where if you click on a app on a overview could get more info... url scenario would be:

```
http://myhost.com                 <-- overview
http://myhost.com/App/app_name    <-- render info about that app
```

But I'm having a small problem understanding routes, thought i did it right:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                "App", // Route name
                "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

And how do I get a hold of id in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would your app rule not be more specific, that is

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "App", // Route name
                "App/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "App", action = "Index", 
                                             id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
                // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Note replaced `{controller}` with `App`